# How do you log asset requests when public_file_server is enabled?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have `config.public_file_server.enabled = true` so that I can have rails serve assets from the /public folder. Is it possible to log http calls for these assets?

I know in development, if you're using sprockets you can see logs like this:

```
Started GET "/assets/application.debug-1e201f4c8ef2a4517d8b188a14b52c38da847bf810ebb9d60e336ecd7152e961.css" for ::1 at 2020-05-22 14:35:50 -0600
Served asset /application.debug-1e201f4c8ef2a4517d8b188a14b52c38da847bf810ebb9d60e336ecd7152e961.css - 200 OK (8ms)
```

But if you precompile your assets and serve them using the `public_file_server` logs no longer appear.

I'm using Rails 5.2.4.3 (and if it matters I'm using sprocket-rails 3.2.1 with sprockets 3.7.2).

Thanks for the help!